# Installing python 2.7, numpy, and pandas

Tags: apt, software-installation, python-2.7

So I've installed ubuntu 12.04 on my PC through Wubi

It came with python 2.7, but it came with python 2.7 in several places... I have a python 2.7 in `/usr/lib`, one in `/usr/local/lib`, and one in `/usr/bin`

not sure if that's supposed to happen but it might be related to my issue.
I went and did

```
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```

it goes and installs a bunch of things, takes about an hour, and then finishes. then I go in and type

```
python
```

and get the usual python screen

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May  6 2015, 13:19:09) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

go ahead and type

```
>>> import pandas
```

and get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

So what's happening? I might be running the "wrong" python, i.e. no the one to which pandas was installed, but how do I know which one it is? and how do I set it so when I type "python" it runs the right one?

Comment: You probably have `/usr/local` in your PATH ahead of `/usr`: check using `which python` and/or `python --version`. Either adjust your PATH, or call `/usr/bin/python` explicitly to get the 'system' version.

Comment: well, I get a different error now :P. Now it's "The installed version of numexpr 1.4.2 is not supported in pandas and will be not be used
The minimum supported version is 2.1", now what?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest numexpr from [Github](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) and follow the installation [procedures](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/INSTALL.rst) listed in the `INSTALL.rst` file. This should hopefully solve the problems with numexpr and pandas